# necessary and sufficient condition for convergence of power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, self-learning

Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{\ln~n}$ is convergent if and only if $0<a<\frac{1}{e}$.

Proof:

$\ln~n<n$ for all $n \geq 1$.Hence the necessary condition for the series to be convergent will be $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{\ln~n}=0$.
And this will happen if $0<a<1$.
Please give me some hint about how to proceed further.

Comment: As you've observed, one of the basic requirements for a series to converge is that the terms must go to zero...but this is not a very strong test, alas -- certainly not an if-and-only-if kind of thing. You'll need something more subtle. More important, though: your title asks about convergence of a power series, and yet this does not appear to be a power series. Did you mistype something?

Answer (score 2):

For $0<a<1$, $a^{\ln(n)}$ is a decreasing sequence. Hence by [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), $$\sum a^{\ln(n)}\text{ is convergent} \iff \sum 2^na^{\ln(2^n)}\text{ is convergent} $$
The last sum is a geometric series, convergent for $0<a<1/e$.

Another approach would be to see that $a^{\ln(n)}=n^{\ln(a)}$, $\sum n^{\ln(a)}$ is a [Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), convergent only for $\ln(a)<-1$.